# Does Hasura (GraphQL) support multiple databases?

Tags: graph

Hi I am setting up [Hasura](https://hasura.io/), the normal setup looks like this:

```
docker run -d --net=host \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@hostname:port/dbname \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

I couldn't find in the [docs](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/docker/index.html#) a way to use multiple databases within the same instance, is it even possible?

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to the developers of Hasura. You might have to purchase a license to receive support though. Reading through the documentation I would say: "No." But I'm not an avid Hasura user.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™ to me. What exactly do you hope to achieve by  "multiple databases within the same instance", and instance of what?

Comment: By same instance I mean running in the same container. I have many data bases with the same structure (tables, columns) for many different clients. The idea was being able to query all using namespaces rather than creating a single container for each client. But never mind.. seems like multiple Databases is not a supported feature in Hasura anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, It's not supported at the moment. You would have to create as many Hasura instances as the number of databases you have. Then use one as the main endpoint and add the others as remote schemas.